# Incompatible Objective C types

Tags: iphone, crash, nsstring, directory, nsurl

I am trying to store the location of my Application's Document Directory in a NSString.

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
```

The code compiles without error, but I get the warning that I am trying to initialize a NSString with a NSURL. When I run the app, the app crashes. I tried casting, but it gave me an error. The book I got it off(Head First iPhone Development) says the code should work. The code is in my appDelegate.m file. Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What does your `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method look like? Show not just the header but the implementation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning an NSURL as Dave DeLong said. However the easiest way to get round this and convert it to an NSString without changing the method, is setting the string to the NSURL's absoluteString.

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] absoluteString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `-applicationDocumentsDirectory` method is returning an `NSURL`.  You want it to return an `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

The methods return a `NSURL`. You must convert the url in `NSString`.
It's very easy. Use a method in `NSURL` class.